# want dynamical dropdown select but dont know why it is not working it is showing blank dropdown in User interface

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drop-down-menu, frontend, angular-fullstack

i used the map function to use the retrieved data.But I am not able to get the dropdown select i  userinterface. but when I checked if the array contains data it works fine when writing to console .but when I use dynamically use select i am not able to use and the dropdown select   appears empty in UI..please look into   this

have a look into this

rest all is working fine only the dropdown appears empty. i tried many ways but I am not   successful .

````
class SignUp extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
        
        M.AutoInit();

        axios.get('http://localhost:8900/department')
      .then(result => {
         this.setState({departmentData:result.data})
      }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error",err)
    });
    }
state = {
    
    departmentData:[]
    };


  render() { 
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sign Up</h5>
          <div className="input-field col s1">
            <span style={{color: 'red'}}> * </span>
            <select id='department'  onChange={this.handleChange}>
              
               {this.state.departmentData.map((dep)=>(
                 
                    <option  key={dep.id} value={dep.id}>{dep.department_name}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <label>Department</label>
          </div>
          
    </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    authstatus:state.auth.authstatus,
    authError: state.auth.authError
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=> {
  return {
    signUp: (creds) => dispatch(signUp(creds))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUp)```


**


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e7Sd.png
````

Comment: Could you inspect the element and include a screenshor, please?

Comment: Also, when asking questions in SO, instead of pasting your whole code, insert a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure @JoshMerrian

Comment: here is the link of the screenshot  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e7Sd.png)

Comment: What exactly do you expect from an empty array? `state = {  departmentData:[]   };`

Comment: departmentData is used to stored the fetched data from the API call